# Connect to VPS using telnet

Tags: networking, telnet

I want to connect my VPS using `telnet` application on port `11368`. My VPS is running Windows Server 2012. I added `11368` port as an allowed port in windows VPS, but when I try to connect using `telnet` I receive this error:

```
Connecting To xx.xx.xxx.xx ...
Could not open connection to the host, on port 11368: Connect failed
```

Can anybody help me solve this?

Comment: come on. You don't want to do this. `telnet` over internet is NOT secure. Microsoft still does not have any better tool?

Comment: @Jakuje this is only for test purpose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make server accept connections you will have to enable/install Telnet Server service on it.

Comment: I'll just add some details to Get Splashed's correct answer.  Furthermore, to do what the question is asking, you need to make the Telnet Server respond to port 11368.  Or, you need to make the Telnet Server respond to port 11368, and have some networking device in the middle (like a firewall) perform port redirection.  The question sounds like a hole was made in the firewall for a specific port, but that's only part of what needs to happen.  Confirm that the desired server is listening for traffic on the machine.